# Why the logs are not update?

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I have a simple `PythonOperator`:

```
def simple():
    print ("start simple")
    for i in range (10):
        time.sleep(0.7)
        print("hello from simple")
    print ("end simple")
```

When looking on the logs window, I need to refresh the page in order to see new logs.

Is it possible for the logs to be updated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Airflow>=2.4.0:**

Supprt for logs auto refresh was added to Grid View (See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/25621))

You can configure the refresh interval by setting [auto_refresh_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#auto-refresh-interval)
(Note this effect other views as well)

**For Airflow<2.4.0:**

There is no option for that.
There is an open feature request to add this ability for future Airflow versions: [Auto-refresh of logs](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/15783)

You can use browser plugins to get this functionality. Chrome has Easy Auto Refresh (and probably many other plugins in that area)

Comment: Note: This is now available in v2.4.0